# Making a textbox stay with the right margin in SSRS when the tablix grows

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a report I've created with Report Builder 3.0 where I put the page number in the upper right corner of the header.  The page is set at 7 inches wide, landscape with the page number at the right margin.

I've got a tablix in the report that can grow (get wider) depending on the data.  Sometimes the page width will be 7 inches, sometimes 10 inches.

I want the page number to always stay with the right margin.  If the margin grows to 10 inches can I have the page number be at 10 inches instead of 7?  And I have to leave it in the header, I can't add the page number to the tablix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width of textboxes is not meant to be dynamic in SSRS by design. Especially within the Header section, there's no way to do what you're asking.

The easiest way to get this behavior would have been to have it in a row on top of the table. Column grouping is the only way to get dynamic horizontal positioning.

Comment: That's true but then it could appear multiple times on the page which wouldn't make sense.  Would be nice if Microsoft gave SSRS some love and updated it.  Thanks for confirming what I thought!  :)

Comment: Actually Globals such as PageNumber can only ever go in the PageHeader/Footer sections of a report